# KeyboardEvent: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've copied some code from Angular's page and visual code is showing an error:

Error for this line:

```
map((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.target.value),
```

Error

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

Code from Angular [website](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage):

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { map, filter, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');

const typeahead = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input').pipe(
  map((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.target.value),
  filter(text => text.length > 2),
  debounceTime(10),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(() => ajax('/api/endpoint'))
);

typeahead.subscribe(data => {
 // Handle the data from the API
});
```

Comment: What is the type of `EventTarget` here ?

Comment: input element....

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Can't reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: @matt Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since, Typescript can't infer the event type. You need to explicitly write the type of the HTMLElement which is your target. For example, if its type is `HTMLInputElement` then you can write the below line:

```
map((e: KeyboardEvent) => (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).value),
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: any chance you know how to get e.target.value from a mouse event? above approach doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this kinda typing, istead of KeyboardEvent use ChangeEvent:

```
map((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => e.target.value),
```